# what is the difference between setting rules in tsconfig.json vs tslint.json?

Tags: typescript

It seems like they both achieve the same result. With TSLint, I had to install a plugin in VSCode? This probably is not preferable should someone in my team use a different editor.

Comment: What rules are you talking about? Those files configure different things.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`tsconfig.json` receives the configuration for the typescript compiler like allowing javascript files, the location of your files, etc.

`tslint.json` is the configuration for TSLint, TSLint helps you to detect bad coding practices or follow a coding style, you can configure its options like disallow unused variables, no logging to the console, etc. Also, TSLint is not just a plugin for vscode, so someone in your team can use the editor of its preference and still use TSLint.

See this links:

- [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)
- [`tslint.json`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/)

Comment: Thanks! tsconfig can also check for `unusedLocals`, so I was confused but your answer makes it clearer.

Comment: Is it correct to say that tsconfig (and TypeScript) are what deal with the actual type checking (and can be used without any additional linter) and TSLint checks for styling and other things, that is intended for use with TypeScript but _doesn't_ do any actual type-checking on its own?

Answer (score 1):

**TSConfig** : Deals with the compiler. Throws an error on compiling bad code. So in Anguar "ng serve" will give you an error
  Ex Error => 
    error TS6138: Property 'dialog' is declared but its value is never read.

**TsLint** : Its to ensure best practice is followed. It does not throw an error on compilation. However, it shows a red line on the code to tell you that your style of coding needs some changes.
On VScode , you need to install a plugin to detect tslint.
On webstorm , it is inbuilt